# Can't make diagonal jump in "I Wanna Kill The Kamilia 2"

Tags: i-wanna-kill-the-kamilia-2

I am playing "I Wanna Kill The Kamilia 2"(I Wanna Be The Guy style fan game) and I am stuck on this room:

[image]

I am always hitting either the spike at the top or at the side. Can someone enlighten me on how to make this diagonal jump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are tough jumps. Get a running start and just as you are about to hit the spike on the right, jump. This will probably take several tries.

Answer (score 0):

Align the kid to be closest to the right spike and then simultaneously press jump and right key.